# Filter datasource by auth.user.id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm a newbie to cakephp and I don't quit get it.

I'm building a system where users login and register some data. And I want the users to only see their own data. How do I do this? I was thinking about making a kind of restriction in the model or do I have to code this in every function (Connected to the views)?

I have a well functioning system With user login etc, but I can't separate the data access to the users.

I can't figure this out and I might think that's a bit because I might not know what to ask about. Hoping that some can give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

You have the logged in users id via `$this->Auth->user('id');`. You then have to set a condition on your find calls where `user_id = $userId`.

```
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

$this->SomeRelatedModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'SomeRelatedModel.user_id' => $userId,
    ),
));
```

You can also pass the `$userId` variable to the model and do your find calls in there (either methods or custom find calls).

If a lot of your models/find calls need to filter by user id, you may want to create a behavior and use beforeFind callback to add the condition to the query.

Answer (score 0):

When user will login, Auth will store Id in session. you can access it by using
`$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')` or `$this->Auth->user('id')` or `AuthComponent::user('id')`

```
$this->User->find('all',array(
                            'conditions'=>array('id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),
                            'fields'=>'...............'));
```